# Can not remove 'Unmamed:' row

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am reading an excel sheet and got the result like below image,

[image]

```
df_result = pd.read_excel(file_path, sheet_name='Person', index=False)
```

I tried to to remove the 'Unnamed:' columns, by using

```
df_result.drop([0], axis=0, inplace=True)
```

But, can not remove this.

**Edit:**

Tried this too,

```
df_result.drop([0], inplace=True)
```

But, removing the 3rd row.(Given `'0'` only)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can skip some number of rows before headers, here 1 row (working because empty rows are excluded by default):

```
df_result = pd.read_excel(file_path, sheet_name='Person', index=False, skiprows=1)
```

Comment: Both options not working, Still removing the 2nd and 3rd row. Actually my first raw is merged one (I hope that is my it comes like 'Unnamed:".

Comment: @VineeshTP - Can you test `header=[1]` or `header=[2]` for first solution and `skiprows=1` for second?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove that row by its index like this:

```py
df_result.drop([0], inplace=True)
```

Comment: tried but, can not drop the "Unnamed:" column. It is deleted the below column (Dropped '0' only.)